# Does The Ranger's Feral Senses Accomplish Anything, RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, invisibility

According to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47727/what-happens-when-an-invisible-creature-is-detected), Invisible, but unhidden enemies are sensed automatically. However, this seems to contradict the Ranger's Feral Senses ability.

> FERAL SENSES: You are also aware of the location of any invisible creature within 30 feet of you, provided that the creature isn’t hidden from you and you aren’t blinded or deafened.

This suggests that being able to sense unhidden invisible enemies is something special that only rangers can do. Is there a consistent ruling under RAW?

Comment: True, but the answers to that one falls under Interpretation #2, which I rebutted.

Comment: Is there any way to re-open that question somehow, since I don't find any of the answers satisfactory?

Comment: What would I do in order to include the new information in that old question, and point out that the old answer is no longer satisfactory, in spite of its many upvotes?  An onlooker will just see what appears to be a satisfactory answer, and move on.

Comment: @Strill Assuming you mean that you want to see new answers on the question I linked, that's what bounties are for.

Comment: And would it be acceptable to rewrite the old question to take into account the new information?

Comment: @Strill Probably not? Your new information consists of two answers to the question and arguments against them. I'm not sure that should really be in a question.

Comment: Definitely not, no. That would count as an unacceptably major edit that would change the intent of the original question. Given the differences, I would actually argue that this is NOT a duplicate, but that you should probably include a reference to the old question in yours

Comment: Allright, I rewrote this question.

Comment: I had this very question a while back:
http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/
(please pardon the lousy title, it was my first post) wax eagle gave a pretty thorough answer that left me unhappy but convinced.