# How does Hunters Mark work when the target goes invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Hunters Mark states

> you have advantage on any Wisdom (Perception) or Wisdom (Survival) check you make to find it.

If the target of the spell casts *invisibility* on itself, how does that interact with the ability of the original caster to find it?

Would the caster have to spend an action to find it with a wisdom check (advantage)? Or does it know where it is and can attack?

Or is the target invisible and follows normal invisibility rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The target is invisible. What that means isn't simple. From Appendix A of the PHB (or Player's Basic Rules), on conditions:

> - An invisible creature is impossible to see without the
>     aid of magic or a special sense. For the purpose of
>     hiding, the creature is heavily obscured. The creature’s
>     location can be detected by any noise it makes
>     or any tracks it leaves.
> - Attack rolls against the creature have disadvantage,
>     and the creature’s attack rolls have advantage.

So the target can't be seen, but it can still be located. If the invisible creature doesn't want people to know where it is, it needs to make a Stealth check to stay hidden. *Hunter's Mark* will give the Ranger advantage on the Perception check needed to find the creature.

Assuming the Ranger's Perception beats the creature's Stealth, the Ranger will be able to tell where the creature is, but the creature will still be invisible, and the Ranger's attacks will still have disadvantage.

You may also want to check out waxeagle's excellent answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/47731/15469) - I think he does a better job than me of explaining the difference between "hidden" and "invisible".

Comment: That makes sense - so I have advantage to know it's position but then disadvantage on the attack roll because it's still invisible. But at least the Hunters Mark helps me find it's general location rather than striking blindly.

Comment: @NautArch Yep, and remember you can tell your allies where he is. Your primary casters should have ways to hurt him without needing the (disadvantaged) attack roll.