# Does Advantage on a target only apply for the first of multiple attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

Any time you get Advantage on a target you roll 2 dice and keep the better roll, and do the opposite for Disadvantage. How does this affect attacks if you have multiple attacks such as from fighters/rangers/monks/warlocks (thirsting blade, eldritch blast), sorcerers (quicken, twin metamagic attack spells), etc.? Is advantage only reserved for the initial attack and not any after that?

Comment: It’s going to depend on the feature giving you advantage. Voting to close “needs details” - which advantage feature is confusing you?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. As I read it, the question is asking, how to determine for how many attack rolls on the attacker's turn does an advantage exist. And there is no clear statement in the rules telling this, so it seems quite fine question to me.

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir There are rules that tell you, which is the issue here. We don't know what rules are causing confusion, so we can't actually answer the question in any meaningful way beyond "it depends" which doesn't actually tell OP how to use any of the rules.

Comment: @thomasMarkov As far as I can see, it's not the rules that seem to be the source of confusion, but the *lack* of a single set of rules. The last sentence is a perfectly clear question for me, I wouldn't even know how to clarify it.

Comment: I have started a meta discussion about this question: [Does this question about multiple attacks and advantage need more details?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11647)

Comment: Is there a specific mechanic giving you advantage that you are asking about? I think this is 'answerable' as is (as shown by Sam's answer), but is that actually a helpful answer for you? If so, then I think this is fine, but if not, then can you clarify how you are gaining advantage so we can better inform you on how that will work.

Answer (score 20):

**It's an attack by attack basis.**
Lots of things can give you advantage or disadvantage. Having advantage on one target with one attack, does not necessarily mean you have it on the second attack of the same target or a different target.
For example, taking the help action, to help your friend in combat gives him advantage on his first attack.   But fighting in Darkness gives you disadvantage on all your attacks.   You have to evaluate each case individually.

Its all explained here: [Advantage and Disadvantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage)

Answer (score 8):

### The source of the advantage will tell you.

Generally, whatever rules text is granting advantage will explicitly tell you what attacks it applies to. If it only applies to the first attack roll, it'll say that. For example, *true strike* says:

> On your next turn, you gain advantage on **your first attack roll** against the target

So there's no doubt that the second attack has no advantage.  But then if the target is Blinded, then

> **Attack rolls** against the creature have advantage

That's all attack rolls, whether it's your first or your fifth.

There are occasionally tricky examples, like if you're attacking from hiding (PHB p.194-195, "Unseen Attackers and Targets"):

> [...] When a creature can't see you, you have advantage on
> **attack rolls** against it.
>
> If you are hidden when you make an attack, you give away your location when the attack hits or misses.

So in that case, *generally* being unseen means you have advantage on every attack, but there's a specific rule that says you stop being hidden when you attack the first time. So in this particular case, your second attack won't have advantage -- not because there's any standard rule that advantage applies only to the first attack, but because the first attack broke your stealth, and that means you are no longer unseen, which means you don't qualify for advantage anymore.

The *invisibility* spell works the same way. "The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell", so you can get advantage on that first attack for being unseen, but you break the spell in the process, so your second attack no longer qualifies.

Comment: There is no rule that says *you stop being hidden*, rather *you give away your location*, which means they do not have to guess to target you. Nothing says you are no longer unseen.

Comment: I disagree. Based on the Hiding sidebar (p.177), I think the intent is that "give away your position" means you've lost your hidden status. They use a number of terms -- "you are discovered", "you give away your position", "you are seen", "notices you", all to mean "hiding is over now". You may still have concealment or cover, but you're not hidden any longer.

Comment: Hidden, as in unaware, is surprise. Unseen and location unknown, you can still react to, you just don't know where to target. Unseen, but location known gets disadvantage, but can otherwise target. Why is this mentioned just before the unseen attackers and why are those rules one right after the other? They make a clear distinction between not seen and not knowing position. It would not be fun to be a rogue invested in sneak with this interpretation.

Comment: @Wyrm We have an entire question on this and [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/157803) states that to give away your location is to no longer be considered hidden

Comment: @Wyrmwood Just to say it here, J. Crawford did a Sage Advice segment on Stealth in Dragon Talk, the official WotC podcast, for 4/27/2017 (https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/james-haeck-dd-writing), in which he was very clear about this. At a bit after 38 minutes, he says "you do give away your location -- in other words you nullify being hidden -- when you hit or miss with an attack". Whether you accept this as official rules or not, it's a pretty definite statement of the rules as intended.

Comment: And I thought errata by tweet was ridiculous. Now it's errata by podcast. Why use precise language when it isn't what you intended?

Comment: @Wyrmwood Honestly? I don't think it *was* precise language. I think the original intent was that "I can't see you but I know exactly where you are" was a kind of weird situation that would only happen if you were invisible or in the dark, but the other guy succeeded on a perception check to find you, and the idea that you need to take a second action to hide in combat after turning invisible was a later development. I think the PHB has a lot of places where the language isn't as carefully chosen because they didn't realize certain phrases were going to become important later.

Comment: Move it to chat oh 46K and I can explain further. Honestly.