# How does Crown of Stars interact with Greater Invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

Suppose I already have the spell [Greater Invisibility](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Greater%20Invisibility#content) cast on me, and then I cast [Crown of Stars](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/crown-of-stars).

From the description of Crown of Stars:

> Seven star-like motes of light appear and orbit your head until the spell ends.

**My questions are: Are the motes invisible?**

**Supposing the motes are visible, do I still get the benefits of Greater Invisibility?**

Again, supposing the motes are visible, "real-world" logic would tell me that if someone were to try to attack me, the difficulty of trying to hit an invisible person would be somewhat mitigated by the fact that I could just aim at the motes. Similar logic seems reasonable for someone targeting me with a spell.

However, (my reading of) the in-game mechanics would tell me that I am still under the invisible condition (as nothing has ended Greater Invisibility) and thus I should still get all the benefits.

Answer (score 13):

Whether the motes themselves are counted as something "the target is wearing or carrying" and become invisible is DM discretion, but many people use a rule of thumb where "wearing or carrying" means any item recorded on the character sheet inventory, in which case the motes would be visible. In either case, the light emitted by the motes is still visible according to [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/928360819548553216).

Whether the enemies can only see the light, or can see the light and the motes, the caster would be considered an unseen attacker (PHB 194) but you would not be hidden. You would still have disadvantage on attacks against you, and advantage on attacks you make, but your location would be known unless you made a successful stealth check. Differences between hidden and invisible outlined [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47727/what-happens-when-an-invisible-creature-is-detected).

Comment: This interpretation also means that a high level spell has a side effect which is mostly an inconvenience (really who hasn't fixed the light issue by that level?). I find that hard to believe, and would find it even harder to rule that way. Side note: while I disagree - this is a well written answer, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

**You'd still have most of the benefits of being invisible**

Greater invisibility only turns yourself, anything you are wearing and anything you are carrying invisible. The motes of light from crown of stars aren't any of these three things.

As such, the motes of light would remain orbiting around your head which would indicate your location. However, you are still invisible so any attack roll against you would be with disadvantage. Enemies would know what your location in though so they would know where to make said attack.

Comment: Does this mean an Ioun stone wouldn't count as being worn or carried? Because they also orbit your head?

Comment: @SeriousBri Ioun stones have a specific line saying that a stone counts as a worn object when orbiting.